# rtmp streaming not working with flowplayer

Tags: rtmp, flowplayer

I've managed to run rtpm movies from Vlcplayer via: rtmp://server_ip:1935/vod/movie_name.flv , but when I'm using them on webpage the video seeking is not working at all. I'm still wondering where might be the problem. Here is my .html page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/js/flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="player" style="width:644px;height:276px;margin:0 auto;text-align:center"></div>
<script>
$f("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", {
clip: {
    url: 'movie.flv',
    scaling: 'fit',
    provider: 'hddn'
},
plugins: {
    hddn: {
        url: "flowplayer.rtmp.swf",
        netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://192.168.0.1:1935/vod'
    }
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used your html file and changed clip url to 'sample.mp4' ( which is the default video in wowza installation) and netConnectionUrl to rtmp://192.168.1.9:1935/vod (based on my ip and wowza VOD application). The player works fine, there is no issue in seeking.

So as I see the html file there is no issue with the code, however you seem to be using flv video and I am using mp4 video ( Video: H.264/AVC & Audio: MPEG-4 AAC).

By any chance are you getting any kind of error message? Or can you host your html file in the cloud somewhere so that the exact issue can be seen for debugging?

Comment: Here is a sample file (use the download option): http://www.fileswap.com/dl/G6lMyUc7fL/

Comment: I tried with  your sample file and it didn't play with my wowza installation, so couldn't check further.